# C# check if current date is 1, 2 or 3 of the month, ignore weekend and additional List<DateTime>

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to check if `DateTime.Now` is in the first 3 business days of each month (from Mon - Fri). I also need to provide a `List<DateTime>` with national holidays and these should be handled accordingly.

If DateTime.Now is Saturday and is 1 of the month, first 3 business days are Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday (3, 4, 5 of the month).

```
    public bool IsBusinessDay()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        DateTime fbd = new DateTime();
        DateTime sbd = new DateTime();
        DateTime tbd = new DateTime();


        DateTime fm = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
        DateTime sm = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 2);
        DateTime tm = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 3);

        // first business day

        if (fm.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            fbd = fm.AddDays(1);
        }
        else if (fm.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            fbd = fm.AddDays(2);
        }
        else
        {
            fbd = fm;
        }

        //second business day

        if (sm.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            sbd = sm.AddDays(1);
        }
        else if (sm.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            sbd = sm.AddDays(2);
        }
        else
        {
            sbd = sm;
        }

        //third business day

        if (tm.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            tbd = tm.AddDays(1);
        }
        else if (tm.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            tbd = tm.AddDays(2);
        }
        else
        {
            tbd = tm;
        }

        if (now == fdb || now == sbd || now == tbd)
        {
           return true;
        }

     return false;
    }
```

Is this a good approach? How can I add a `List<DateTime>` with holidays and check that the current date is not holiday?

I have a feeling I'm over thinking this, and thinking it in a bad way. I don't know why but same feeling tells me there is an easier way to do it.

Comment: How do you define your holidays? DateTime has a 'Year' part, which mean you can't simply set a DateTime object to (e.g.) September 1st and expect it to 'raise a flag' each year. You need to create a descriptor objects that will describe the recurring date and then check the current date against it

Comment: Just a note regarding your interface: you'd probably be better off accepting any `DateTime` rather than hard-coding it only work with `DateTime.Now`. (A zero-parameter overload could call the one-parameter overload with `DateTime.Now` though.) From there, a helper function `DateTime GetNextBusinessDay(DateTime day)` would simplify the implementation.

Comment: @Nissim holidays aren't always on the same month/day each year, so you'd need full DateTime to know if a given date is a holiday. The list supplied to this function only needs to contain the holiday dates for the current month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want.  You'll have to supply the set of holidays.

```
public static bool IsFirstThreeBusinessDays(DateTime date, HashSet<DateTime> holidays)
{
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
    int businessDaysSeen = 0;

    while (businessDaysSeen < 3)
    {
        if (dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && 
            dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && 
            !holidays.Contains(dt))
        {
            if (dt == date.Date)
            {
                return true;
            }

            businessDaysSeen++;
        }

        dt = dt.AddDays(1);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: One small correction: instead of: `if (dt == date)` should be: `if (dt.Date == date.Date)`. As we need to compare only the date without the time. Otherwise it will never be equal if the date parameter is `DateTime.Now`

Comment: You are correct, though it only needs to be `if(dt == date.Date)` because the time part of `dt` is always zero anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using LINQ.

```
public static bool IsFirstThreeBusinessDays(DateTime date, HashSet<DateTime> holidays)
{
    var query =
        Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month))
            .Select(o => new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, o))
            .Where(o => o.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && o.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday
                && !holidays.Contains(o))
            .Take(3);

    return query.Contains(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I didn't read the question carefully enough, although parts of my old answer are still applicable. The approach I would take here is to create a method that enumerates the business days of the month, then take 3 from that.

Here's how:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> BusinessDaysOfMonth(DateTime time)
{
    var month = new DateTime(time.Year, time.Month, 1);
    var nextMonth = month.AddMonths(1);

    var current = month;
    while(current < nextMonth)
    {
        if (IsWeekday(current) && !IsHoliday(current))
        {
            yield return current;
        }
        current = current.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

(note that some methods are taken from below). Then, all you need where you want to use this is:

```
// Get first three business days
var firstThreeBizDays = BusinessDaysOfMonth(DateTime.Now).Take(3);

// Check if today is one of them
var result = firstThreeBizDays.Contains(DateTime.Today);
```

---

OLD ANSWER:

Ok, so it looks like there's three conditions you need to ensure. They are:

- It is the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd day of the month
- It is not Saturday or Sunday
- The current date is not contained in some set of dates representing holidays

This translates fairly straightforwardly to code:

```
public static bool IsFirstThreeDays(DateTime time) => time.Day < 4;

public static bool IsWeekday(DateTime time)
{
    var dow = time.DayOfWeek;
    return dow != DayOfWeek.Saturday && dow != DayOfWeek.Sunday;
}

public bool IsHoliday(DateTime time)
{
    ISet<DateTime> holidays = ??; // Decide whether this is a member or an arg
    return holidays.Contains(time.Date);
}
```

Note that the `holidays` set needs to contain the `Day` component of any `DateTime` from each holiday.

Now your method is presumably just:

```
public static bool IsDayWhatYouWant()
{
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    return IsFirstThreeDays(now) && IsWeekday(now) && !IsHoliday(now);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the first 3 business days of the month, not just the first 3 days.

Comment: It should be first 3 business days of the month. If 1 of the month is Saturday, that means first business day is Mon, Tue, Wed (3,4,5). If 1 of the month is Friday, the first 3 business days are Fri, Mon, Tue (1, 4, 5 of the month).

Comment: @juharr Ohh, that complicates things a bit. I'll see if it can be done with an IEnumerable.